# The code that I have tried is not displaying the expected output. How can I rectify my code which is related to patterns?

Tags: java

I need to print a square pattern where the number increases as per the row, for example consider variable 'i' which represents row value, if you initialize i=1 and increase the value till 'n' which is user input using while loop, the first row will print 1, second row will print 2 and so on till it reaches the value 'n'. Additionally I created variable for column and named it 'j' whose value also increases till it reaches n.

The output that I'm getting though is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJoDr.png)
The code that I have written is: (java)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUu9J.png)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int i =1;
        while(i<=n){
            int j = 1;
            while(j<=n){
                System.out.println(i);
                j=j+1;
            }
            System.out.println();
            i=i+1;
        }
```

Why is the output for the above code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77avT.png) instead of

- 1111
- 2222
- 3333
- 4444

Please help me out.

Comment: you are using println, which prints and goes to the next line

Comment: Just think about what each line of your code _should_ do, then read the JavaDocs on the methods you're using and find out what they _are_ doing.

Comment: Instead of System.out.println(i) use System.out.print(i). It will print the number in same line.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

The [doc states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)) the following and you know it

> Prints an integer and then terminates the line

---

#### Fix

Use `print` instead

```
while (i <= n) {
    int j = 1;
    while (j <= n) {
        System.out.print(i);
        ++j;
    }
    System.out.println();
    ++i;
}
```

---

#### Improvements

Could be a little bit nicer with for loops

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Using `String.repeat`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i).repeat(n));
}
```

Comment: Ok. Sure it looks a lot better with for loops. Thanks!